# String bundles work differently in Firefox 25?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I've been getting some error reports that my Firefox extension is no longer working in Firefox 25. I can't reproduce the error but someone sent me the error they're seeing:

TypeError: this.rehostImageBundle.getString is not a function @ chrome://rehostimage/content/rehostimage.js:196

rehostimage.js:

```
this.rehostImageBundle = document.getElementById("us.engy.rehostImage.bundle");
...
var stringValue = this.rehostImageBundle.getString("message.uploadprogress");
```

These are running in the same function, at the same scope. That last line is line 196.

rehostimage.xul:

```
<!DOCTYPE window SYSTEM "chrome://rehostimage/locale/rehostimage.ent">
<overlay id="rehostimage" 
     xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
  <script type="application/x-javascript" src="chrome://rehostimage/content/rehostimage.js"/>
  ...

  <popup id="contentAreaContextMenu">
    <stringbundleset id="us.engy.rehostImage.stringbundles">
      <stringbundle id="us.engy.rehostImage.bundle" src="chrome://rehostimage/locale/rehostimage.properties"/>
    </stringbundleset>
    ...
  </popup>
  ...
</overlay>
```

So it seems like when it calls getElementById it's not coming up with a [stringbundle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/stringbundle), but I don't know why it would do this, or why it would only happen with some setups.

I checked [Add-on Compatibility for Firefox 25](http://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2013/09/30/compatibility-for-firefox-25/) but didn't see anything about string bundles.

Anyone run into this or have any ideas?

Comment: Cannot reproduce myself, using your AMO version. The code looks a bit confusing but OK all-in-all. I'd expect that some other add-on interferes with your add-on either removing your `<stringbundle>` (or any parent node) or removing the overlay target node or changing it's id before your overlay gets applied. Anyway, I see no way to diagnose this without more help from an affected user (proving list of installed add-ons for starters, or being willing to install some debug version which you'd have to prepare).

Comment: It does appear to be an extension conflict... I got in contact with someone having the problem and it works for them on a clean profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be an extension conflict with Menu Editor. Something about Firefox 25 changed how it interacted with the context menu, which removed the resource bundle I had included in the context menu overlay. I moved the bundle to the addon bar overlay and that resolved the conflict.